# Insert API response into many rows at once - psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to `INSERT` a resulting dict from an API into my db, so far I can insert one item at a time.

This is my code:

```
import json
import requests
import psycopg2

def my_func():
    response = requests.get("https://path/to/api/")
    data = response.json()

    while data['next'] is not None:
        response = requests.get(data['next'])
        data = response.json()
        for item in data['results']:
            try:
                connection = psycopg2.connect(user="user",
                                          password="user",
                                          host="127.0.0.1",
                                          port="5432",
                                          database="mydb")
                cursor = connection.cursor()

                postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO table_items (NAME) VALUES (%s)"""
                record_to_insert = item['name']
                cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, (record_to_insert,))
                connection.commit()
                count = cursor.rowcount
                print (count, "success")
            except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
                if(connection):
                    print("error", error)
            finally:
                if(connection):
                    cursor.close()
                    connection.close()

my_func()
```

So, this one is working, but for example if I want to insert into `table_items`, not just on `name` row, but let's say, `name, address, weight, cost_per_unit`, from that table, then I will change these lines of code:

```
postgres_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO table_items (NAME, ADDRESS, WEIGHT, COST_PER_UNIT) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)'
            record_to_insert = (item['name']['address']['weight']['cost_per_unit'])
```

Then it will throw:

> Failed to insert record into table_items table string indices must be integers
>       PostgreSQL connection is closed

I mean, the first version, with just one field works perfectly, but I need to insert into the other 3 fields everytime, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix the syntax when you call the item attributes to define the parameters, and also change the object you pass to the parameterized query, since `record_to_insert` is already a tuple :

```
postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO table_items 
    (NAME, ADDRESS, WEIGHT, COST_PER_UNIT) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"""

record_to_insert = (item['name'], 
                    item['address'], 
                    item['weight'], 
                    item['cost_per_unit'])

cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert) # you can pass the tuple directly
```